# Python : fill cuboid with spheres

Tags: python, comparison, imaging

I was wondering how to create spheres in a cuboid. This cuboid (50,50,50) is enclosed with lots of points and  all I wanted is to get the points position and its value inside the sphere (radius = 2).

Any idea/advise/code/info greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sphere with its center (i,j,k) and cuboid (x0,y0,z0):

```
points_in_sphere = (x0 - i)**2 + (y0 - j)**2 + (z0 - k)**2 <= (radius)**2
```

Extract the coordinates of the points:

```
x1,y1,z1 = np.argwhere(points_sphere)[:,0], np.argwhere(points_sphere)[:,1], np.argwhere(points_sphere)[:,2]
```

Print the point values:

```
print cubiod[x1,y1,z1]
```